# Flexbox layouting with space-between

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

i'm working with flexbox with `justify-content: space-between` & `flex-wrap: wrap`,
so each item separates as far as possible.
But i want to if the container space is not sufficient, the item(s) are wrapped to the next row
but keep the items placement symmetrical (centered).

See the illustration below:

[image]

Update: the **alone box** is might in somewhere row:
[image]

It works for `space-around` & `space-evenly` but not for `space-between`.

Any idea for making this behavior? Maybe using `display: grid` can archive similar result.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <p>symmetrical => works:<p/>
  <div class="container long">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <hr />
  
  <p>non symmetrical => fail:<p/>
  <div class="container short">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <p>symmetrical => works:<p/>
  <div class="container med">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <p>non symmetrical => fail:<p/>
  <div class="container med">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="weird"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.container>*{
  inline-size: 100px;
  block-size: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;

  row-gap: 10px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 20px;
}

.long {
  inline-size: 400px;
}
.short {
  inline-size: 250px;
}
.med {
  inline-size: 350px;
}

.weird {
  inline-size: 300px;
}
```

[See the sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-wtqj7?file=/index.html:0-536)

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Please post the code till which you have attempted, so that we could check the same

Comment: updated. see my post above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting an extra css rule on the last child of .short container, but this is a hack. space-between is expected to work like this.

```
.short div:last-child {margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: I updated the case, see my post. The **alone box** is might on any row randomly.